# not getting data from the webservice

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Iam new to iphone development, i want to get data from the web service using JSON parsing here is the code

```
-(void)loadDataSource

  {

   NSString *URLPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blogs"];


  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLPath];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];


 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    NSInteger responseCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

    if (!error)// && responseCode == 200)
    {
        id res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

        if (res && [res isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {

           self.dict=[res objectForKey:@"responseData"];  
          self.items = [self.dict objectForKey:@"entries"];
            [self dataSourceDidLoad];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [self dataSourceDidError];
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        [self dataSourceDidError];
    }
}];
```

}

when i run this code it displays nothing and code for collection view at index is

```
- (PSCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView viewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index 

{

NSDictionary *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:index];

PSBroView *v = (PSBroView *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableView];
if (!v) 
{
    v = [[PSBroView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

[v fillViewWithObject:item];

return v;
```

}

below the code for fillViewWithObject

```
- (void)fillViewWithObject:(id)object
{
[super fillViewWithObject:object];

self.captionLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"title"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently didn't check your error, because when I run this I get "bad URL" as the error. I also get a compiler warning, "more % conversions than arguments". That's because of the % in your url string. You shouldn't be using stringWithFormat -- just pass the literal string, and it should work:

```
NSString *URLPath = @"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blogs";
```

I see this error (or just wasted code) a lot. You shouldn't use stringWithFormat unless you are supplying a format string and arguments.